# Using german characters with TProcess within the CommandLine Parameter

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to use german characters like "ö,a,ü" in combination with `TProcess` within the `CommandLine` parameter. More specifically I'm trying to open an Explorer window that shows a folder which includes the characters in it's name/path. Here's the code:

```
strFolderPath := '"C:\FolderName_Ä"'
RunProgram := TProcess.Create(nil);
RunProgram.CommandLine := 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe ' + strFolderPath;
RunProgram.Execute;
RunProgram.Free;
```

Apparently using ü/ä/ö in the `CommandLine` Property doesn't work. Which way can I use to encode them properly within the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me if I convert to strFolderpath (which is probably UTF8 if your program is developed with Lazarus) to Ansi:

```
  uses
    LazUTF8;

  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    strFolderPath: String;
    P: TProcess;
  begin
    strFolderPath := UTF8ToWinCP('d:\äöü');
    P := TProcess.Create(nil);
    P.CommandLine := 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe ' + strFolderPath;
  // better:
  //  P.Executable := 'C:\windows\explorer.exe';
  //  P.Parameters.Add(strFolderPath);
    P.Execute;
    P.Free;
  end;
```

Note also that the TProcess.CommandLine is deprecated. The recommended way is to put the binary into TProcess.Executable and add the parameters, one by one, by TProcess.Parameters.Add(...).

Comment: thank you, does that mean that the property CommandLine (possibly) won't be available anymore in future versions?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes "deprecated" tags are forgotten and remain in the code for ever, but you cannot be sure. Better to act.

Comment: Commandline is a construct that requires parsing on non Windows targets. It is deprecated (as in not recommended for new use) for ages, simply because as your program expands, you will find new constructs that don't work this way and need more escaping quoting etc. Therefore it was decided to only recommend a way that doesn't need escaping or quoting and works for all targets. Change requests relating to commandline parsing/quoting will be closed as "won't fix"

Answer (score 0):

In current trunk and the 3.2.x branch, you can use TProcess from the processunicode unit, which works with unicodestring.

This also works for programs without lazarus and without the lazarus "utf8hack"

Comment: thanks. so if I understand right, I need to update to at least 3.2 (currently I'm still working with 3.0.0). How do I make sure, that I use "TProcess from the processunicode unit"?

Comment: 3.2.0-beta is a future version that is being prepared, I.O.W. a development version that still changes daily.  Updating is done by compiling SVN.